# Getting error when passing variables in program

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

I am relatively new to fortran so I know that I probably have some silly mistakes in this code, but when I compile the code I get this error:

```
 gfortran hw6_.f95
hw6_.f95:84:37:

   84 |          call Quicksort(n, lo, p-1, A(n))
      |                                         1
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘a’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(4)
hw6_.f95:85:37:

   85 |          call Quicksort(n, p+1, hi, A(n))
      |                                         1
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘a’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(4)
hw6_.f95:83:9:

   83 |      p = Partition(n, lo, hi, A(n))
      |         1
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘a’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(4)
hw6_.f95:43:34:

   43 |    call Quicksort(n, lo, hi, A(n))
      |                                  1
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘a’ at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to REAL(4)
```

I have no idea where the program is getting that the A(n) is being declared as an integer when there is nowhere that it is declared that way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
program Do_QuickSort

   ! Name:Nik Wrye
   ! course: CDS251 
   ! Assignment: Homework #6
   ! Due Date: October 14th, 2021
   ! Description: This program takes an array that the user inputs and sorts it using quick sort method.

    implicit none
    
    ! Declare Variables: 
    ! n -- the length of the dataset
    ! A -- the array of values to be sorted
    ! fName -- the name of the file containing the data to be processed
    ! Note: Please declare additional variables as needed!
    integer :: lo, hi, i, n
    real*4, allocatable :: A(:)
    character*50 :: fName

    
    ! Ask the user which file to sort
   print*, 'What is the input file: '
   read(*,*) fName

   ! Read input file:
   ! Open the file and read the data from it into an array.
   ! Do not forget to allocatethe required memory.
   ! Then close the file      
       
   open(42,file=fName)
   ! Read the number of values
   read(42,*) n
   ! Allocate memory for the array of values
   allocate (A(n))
 
   close(42)
   
   lo = 1
   
   hi = n
   
   ! Sort the ENTIRE array you read with the QuickSort subroutine below
   call Quicksort(n, lo, hi, A(n))

   ! Write results to file.
   open(43,file='Output.txt')

   ! Write to the file the number of values n
   
   write(43,*) n
   
   ! Write the results (n followed by the sorted numbers) to a file.
   ! Then, close the file and deallocate the memory used to store the array 
   ! Write to the file the sequence of values in their ordered form (one value per line)
   do i = 1, n
      write(43,*) A(i)
   enddo
    
   print*,'Done!'
    
   !Close file
   close(43)
   
   ! Deallocate the array A memory
   deallocate(A)
   end program 
 
 recursive subroutine QuickSort(A, n, lo, hi)
 
    ! Recursive subroutine that implements quicksort. The subroutine should partition an 
    ! array of values A of length n from A(lo) to A(hi) by first calling the Partition 
    ! function (defined below) and finding the index P of the partitioning cell. Then, the Do_Quick
 
    implicit none
    
    ! Declare varialbes. Remember to declare the type of the Partition function below
    integer :: lo, hi, p, partition, n
    real*4 :: A(n)

    ! Complete the subroutine code below. See the Quick Sort pseudocode in the class 
    ! notes 
     if (lo < hi) then 
     p = Partition(n, lo, hi, A(n))
     call Quicksort(n, lo, p-1, A(n))
     call Quicksort(n, p+1, hi, A(n))
        
   endif
   return 

 end subroutine QuickSort
 
 function Partition(A, n, lo, hi) result(p)

    ! Partition function goes through partiion once and moves small numbers
    ! to the left and larger numbers to the right and returns the Partition
    ! location.
 
    implicit none
 
    ! Declare the variables.

        real*4 :: temp, A(n)
        integer :: i, lo, hi, pivot, p, n
   
    ! Store the pivot value in a variable.
        pivot = A(hi)
        p = A(lo)
   ! partition sub-array and determine the location of P in the array A.
   !setting up do loop for the actual sorting
   do i = lo, hi-1
   
   !conditional if statement 
       if (A(i) .le. pivot) then 
   
   !Move the pivot value into the location P by swapping values.
   !swapping the elements
            temp = A(i)
            A(i) = A(p)
            A(p) = temp
        endif
        p = p+1
    end do 
    
    temp = A(p)
    A(p) = A(hi)
    A(hi) = temp
    
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `Quicksort` expects arguments `(A, n, lo, hi)`, i.e. a `real` array followed by three `integer` scalars.

However, on line 43 you're calling `Quicksort` as

```
call Quicksort(n, lo, hi, A(n))
```

i.e. you're supplying it with three `integer` scalars followed by a `real` scalar. So the error message is complaining that the first expected argument, `A`, which expects a `real`, is being passed an `integer`, `n`.

Line 43 of your code should probably read

```
call Quicksort(A, n, lo, hi)
```

Note also the change from `A(n)` to `A`, so that you're passing the whole array `A` to the routine rather than just its final element.

tl;dr you're passing the arguments to `Quicksort` in the wrong order.

Comment: Personally I would avoid using the non-standard `real*8` and the non-portable `real( 4 )` in an answer, especially to one that is for help with an assignment when learning the language.